# Modeling a hanging, oscillating chain as a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> A flexible chain of length $\ell$ is hanging from one end at $x=0$ while oscillating horizontally (along the chain's transverse). Assume that gravity affects the chain and that the horizontal oscillations are very small.

From *Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction, 2nd Ed.* (Strauss, pg. 19). Suppose the chain's density is constant and has the value $\rho$. Suppose that gravitational acceleration is $g>0$. Also I will liberally use Newton's law, $\textbf F=m\textbf a$, with $m=\int_D\rho$.

**Thoughts:** Let $U(x,t)$ describe the chain's "amplitude" at location $x$ and time $t$. Then the vector describing the chain's location can be written $\langle x,U(x,t)\rangle$, and the vector tangential along the chain's length is therefore $\langle1,U_x(x,t)\rangle$. The component of the chain's tension $T$ which counteracts gravity must be

$$\frac{T}{\sqrt{1+U_x(x,t)^2}}=-\int_0^\ell\rho g\,dx$$

so

$$T=-\sqrt{1+U_x(x,t)^2}\int_0^\ell\rho g\,dx$$

Since the chain's oscillations are "small", we can assume that $U_x(x,t)^2\to0$, hence $T=-\int_0^\ell\rho g\,dx$. The horizontal component of tension gives us our oscillations, thus

$$\frac{|T|U_x(x,t)}{\sqrt{1+U_x(x,t)^2}}=\int\rho U_{tt}(x,t)\,dx$$

Using the small oscillations assumption,

$$\begin{split}|T|U_x(x,t)=&\int\rho U_{tt}(x,t)\,dx
\\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}|T|U_x(x,t)=&\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int\rho U_{tt}(x,t)\,dx\end{split}$$

Obtaining the form for the PDE,

$$|T|U_{xx}-\rho U_{tt}=0$$

As for boundary conditions, the only one obviously supplied is $U(0,t)=0$.

**Question 1:** Is the PDE correct? Do the boundary conditions capture the information given in the question?

**Question 2:** I don't understand why the smallness of oscillations on the chain allowing us to assume that $U_x(x,t)^2\to0$ is an OK assumption at all. How can we be certain that this doesn't impact the overall solution overly much? What is meant by "small" anyways? The PDE text doesn't explain it in great detail at all.

Comment: You have a 2.Order PDE. You need two boundary conditions and two initial conditions.

Comment: @MJay1985 I can only give what I'm given. Not enough information for boundary conditions or initial conditions beyond this, unless I missed something?

Comment: But the Chain has to be fixed at the other end. Or it would just fall down and stay there. You also need to assume some initial shape of the chain e.g. $U(x,t=0)=U_0(x)$. Ans also some initial velocity profile $\partial_x U(x,t=0)=V_0(x)$.

Comment: Well, the chain is fixed at one end, the other I imagine is just hanging there. But I should mention unspecified functions describing shape and profile.

Comment: Normally you must to that or you can't solve your PDE. Its like a mass spring system without damping or friction. If you initial deflection of your mass is zero the mass will stay there for ever, but if your initial displacement is not zero the mass will oszillate for eternity :). Maybe imagine it this way. You have a Chain between two walls. Then ask yourself, does it make a difference if you pull the chain down or up and then leave it alone (initinital condition in position)?